# SQL : Set operation to perform logic for each record

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

[image: Table 1 - Escalation, table2 - Data]

Table 1 - Escalation, Table2 - Data

The requirement is : for all record in data table, we need to perform escalation.

Example 1 - record 1 in data table, year is 2014 and economic year is 2018. So, we need to escalate the value(600) from 2014 to 2015, then to 2016, then to 2017.
So, final value will be 600*5*6*7

Example 2 - record 3 in data table will be escalated twice - from 2015 to 2016 and then to 2017. So, final value will be 1000*6*7
This has to be performed for all records in data table.

I don't want to use cursor as i have 3 million records to do this.

Please suggest some idea to perform using Set Operation

```
    create table data
    ([year] int,
    value int,
    economic_year int,
    modelid int,
    shopid int)

    create table escalation
    ([year] int,
    shopid int,
    value_es int
    )


    insert into data
    values(
    2014,600,2018,5,1),
    (2014,600,2018,5,1),
    (2015,1000,2018,5,1),
    (2016,2000,2018,5,1),
    (2017,3000,2018,5,1)

    insert into escalation
    values
    (2014,1,4),
    (2015,1,5),
    (2016,1,6),
    (2017,1,7)


    select * from escalation
    select * from data
```

Comment: The answer you seek [begins here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I have added the create table script. @SeanLange

Comment: Is economic_year 2018 for all the records you are updating?

Comment: @JeremyJ. : For the sample data above, Yes. But in my application, it is a drop-down where a user can select a particular year and then I need to do the rest of calculation with a similar logic.

Comment: How would the other recirds be handled?

Comment: Record 5 wont have any escalation calculation, so out put expected is 3000.

Comment: Is the value_es the last digit in the year? You could do something with factorials...

Comment: No no ...that just happens to be correct, but the value can be any number..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is have a third table that you prepopulate with all the possible "update paths" and the respective values. For example, if your year is 2014 and economic year is 2018, then your multiplier (value_es) is 120 (4*5*6). Something like this:

[image: sample table]

You would join the data table to this new table on two columns data.year = start_year and data.economic_year = econ_year. Then, your new value would be data.value * val.

You could create a simple ETL process that initially populates this new table and updates it when the calendar rolls over to a new year. Let me know what you think or if you have any questions.

Comment: I think this should solve my problem. Please give me sometime to implement and check back. Will ask any questions if needed or will accept the answer is all looks good...Thanks a lot for quick help by the way :)